# don't submit form if form validation fail

Tags: php, javascript, dom

I write the

```
<form action='test.php' method='post'>
.............
<submit onclick='validate();'></submit>
</form>

function valiadte(){
  if(true){
      var form = getElementByID(........);
      form.submit();
  }
  else alert('error');
}
```

but it sill go to test.php if fail.
how do I avoid it go to test.php if fail or I can pass some message to the test.php?

Thx in advance.

original source code:

```
            <form id="tabS" method="post" action="stdRegister.php">
                    <label>Account</label>
                    <input id="stdAccount" name="account" type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge" onblur="validateAccountAndID(this,document.getElementById('stdAccountHelp'));">
                    <span class="help-block" id="stdAccountHelp"></span>
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input id="stdPassword" name="password" type="password" value="" class="input-xlarge" onblur="validatePassword(this,document.getElementById('stdPasswordHelp'));">
                    <span class="help-block" id="stdPasswordHelp"></span>
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input id="stdName" name="name" type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge" onblur="validateName(this,document.getElementById('stdNameHelp'));">
                    <span class="help-block" id="stdNameHelp"></span>
                    <label>IDNumber</label>
                    <input id="stdID" name="idNumber" type="text" value="" class="input-xlarge" onblur="validateAccountAndID(this,document.getElementById('stdIDHelp'));">
                    <span class="help-block" id="stdIDHelp"></span>
                    <label>Department</label>
                    <select id="stdDepartment" name="department">
                        <?php
                            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                                    echo"<option>";
                                    echo $row['department'];
                                    echo"</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <label>Grade</label>
                    <select id="stdGrade" name="grade">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                    <div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitStudetForm();">Create Account</button>
                    </div>
                    <span class="help-block" id="stdRegisterHelp"></span>
                </form>

function submitStudentForm(){
    var form = document.getElementById('tabP');
    if(
        validateAccountAndID(document.getElementById('stdAccount'),document.getElementById('stdAccountHelp')) 
        && validatePassword(document.getElementById('stdPassword'),document.getElementById('stdPasswordHelp')) 
        && validateName(document.getElementById('stdName'),document.getElementById('stdNameHelp')) 
        && validateAccountAndID(document.getElementById('stdID'),document.getElementById('stdIDHelp')) ){
       form.submit();
       alert("success");
    }
    else {
        alert("Something wrong in the form. Please check again!");
        return false;
        //window.location.href='index.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you testing to be true?

Comment: form validation like length regexp

Comment: Just as an FYI so you don't have to interfere with the default submission, you could use the `onsubmit` function to perform your validation. This way you would simply `return true;` if all validation passed and the form would continue to submit (without you having to get the form and manually submit it again) or `return false;` in which case the submission would stop and leave you on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have the function `return false` in the `else` case.

```
function validate(){
  if(true){
      return true;
  }
  else {
       alert('error');
      return false;
  }
}
```

And you would change your html to:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="validate()">
```

Comment: Can you show your exact code?  And did you make the change to the html as well?  Keep in mind that right now it says `if (true)` and I was assuming you have some actual validation in place of "true", otherwise it will always return true and will submit.

Comment: @Liang-YuPan, note that in the new code you pasted you have mispelled your validation function when calling it: `onclick="submitStudetForm()`.  Correct the mispelling and try again.  If that still doesn't work, make the other changes I suggest above.

Comment: I finally use onsubmit="return validate();" success but still don't know why. Thx four your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use this to stop the form submission :

```
else {
  alert('error');
  return false;
}
```

By the way, your function name is "valiadte" and not "validate".